# Rails group by and process array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, data-structures, hash

I have an array of ruby hashes. This is the structure:

```
[ {
  :question_id => 1
  :topic_id    => 2
  }
  {
  :question_id => 1
  :topic_id    => 3
  }
  {
  :question_id => 2
  :topic_id    => 1
  }
  ...
]
```

I want to group this by `question_id` and further concatenate the `topic_id` so that it looks like:

```
  [ {
      :question_id => 1
      :topic_id    => 2,3
      }
      {
      :question_id => 2
      :topic_id    => 1
      }
      ...
    ]
```

`group_by` allows me to group but not concatenate on `topic_id`.

```
result.group_by{|h| h[:question_id]}.map do |question_id, hash|
  { question_id: question_id, topic_id: hash.map{|h| h[:topic_id].to_s + ","}}
end
```

What is a clean ruby way to do this?

Comment: Could you show what code you have tried?

Comment: Updated the question with the code.

Comment: @VarunJain, you can't simply turn the value of a Ruby hash into a comma delimited list __unless__ the value is an _array_.

Answer (score 2):

replace `hash.map{|h| h[:topic_id].to_s + ","}` with `hash.map{|h| h[:topic_id]}.join(',')`

```
result = [ { :question_id => 1, :topic_id    => 2 },{:question_id => 1, :topic_id    => 3 },{  :question_id => 2, :topic_id    => 11 }]
result.group_by{|h| h[:question_id]}.map{ |q_id, hashes_array|  {:question_id => q_id, :topic_id => hashes_array.map{|hash| hash[:topic_id]}.join(',') } }
```

I hope that you will get result for which you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

With just the removal of the `.to_s + ","` bit, your code already seems correct?

```
result = [{:question_id => 1, :topic_id => 2}, {:question_id => 1, :topic_id => 3}, {:question_id => 2, :topic_id => 1}]

result.group_by{|h| h[:question_id]}.map { |question_id, hash| { question_id: question_id, topic_id: hash.map{|h| h[:topic_id]}} }
=> [{:question_id=>1, :topic_id=>[2, 3]}, {:question_id=>2, :topic_id=>[1]}]
```

This seems to match what you are looking for?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?